# Is there a shorthand for AsRef<T> in Rust?

Tags: string, rust, reference, type-parameter

Is there suggar for AsRef? Preferably in the stable channel.

I'm frequently declaring string-like parameters with as ref to make it easier to interop with various incantations of strings (String, &str, &String, etc.) as so :

```
fn Fun<S: AsRef<str>>(my: S) { ... my.as_ref() ...}
```

However now reading back those implementations after a while, it's visually taking more real estate in the code than I feel it should, is there a way to shrink usages? For instance not having to declare a type param explicitly, not having to call as_ref() explicitly, etc.

Looking at [this cheatsheet](https://cheats.rs/#tab-variance-2), [the book](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/first-edition/borrow-and-asref.html), and [the doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) does not suggest that there  is.

Best.

Comment: No there isn't. You could get rid of the type parameter by using the `impl Trait` syntax and store the reference in a `let my_ref = my.as_ref()` binding instead, but that's about it.

Comment: Do you even need to use `AsRef`? just taking `&str` as a parameter will accept both `&str` and `&String` types due to deref coercion: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5fa801a9ba5babf514150cf49557c515)

Comment: @kmdreko String (without ref) must work also.

Answer (score 7):

You could declare a [trait alias](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1733-trait-alias.html) (requires nightly) and/or use [impl trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/impl-trait.html)

```rust
trait AsStr = AsRef<str>;


fn my_func(arg: impl AsStr) {

  arg.as_ref() ...

}
```

Comment: Can't use trait alias since I'm on stable but +1 for impl trait, switching to that for now :)

Comment: Why not use a type instead ? 

```rust
type AsStr = AsRef<str>;
```